# How to convert time in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

How do i convert this date `1/6/2016 12:00:00 AM` to `2016-01-06T00:00:00` in C#. I need to display it like that.

```
EstimatedDate.ToString("");
```

SOLVE:

```
string.Format("{0:s}", EstimatedDate)
```

Comment: Is `1/6/2016 12:00:00 AM` a `string` or `DateTime`?

Comment: @SonerGönül DateTime

Comment: @Reynan use `ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")` on your `DateTime`

Comment: @Ian is there any shortcut like To.String("S")

Comment: @Reynan I think you got the answer. See Mr. Soner Gonul's

Comment: @Reynan It is not `To.String` but `ToString` and not `S` but `s`. Custom date and time format specifiers are case sensitive. Also for a `DateTime` instance, `string.Format("{0:s}", EstimatedDate)` is equal to `EstimatedDate.ToString("s")`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [The `"s"` standard format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Sortable) which is exactly generate the result you want.

```
EstimatedDate.ToString("s");
```

From documentation;

> The pattern reflects a defined standard ([ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)), and the property
>   is read-only. Therefore, it is always the same, regardless of the
>   culture used or the format provider supplied. The custom format string
>   is `"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss"`.

Comment: "No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments"

Comment: @Reynan This `DateTime.ToString(string)` overload exist since .NET 2.0 version. Are you _really_ sure about that? Or are you _really_ sure your `EstimatedDate` is `DateTime`?

Comment: Im using LINQ to SQL it is set to Datetime. shipmentmodel.EstimatedDate.ToString("s");

Comment: @Reynan So? When you hover the mouse on `EstimatedDate`, you still see it's type as `DateTime`, right?

Answer (score 4):

`EstimatedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");` sill give you the desired format

For a full example of:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("1/6/2016 12:00:00 AM");
string dateStr = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
```

**Update from @soner-gönül:** - This method is Cultural *dependent*, where as `"s"` is not. `CurrentCulture` must be **Gregorian Calendar** for this to work.

[cs](/questions/tagged/cs) [timestamp](/questions/tagged/timestamp) [time](/questions/tagged/time)

Comment: Be careful, if you don't use any `IFormatProvider` as a second parameter, the result _might_ be different if `CurrentCulture` setting use a different calendar rather than Gregorian Calendar. Based on your example; `date.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ar-SA"))` will generate `1437-08-25T00:00:00` as a representation. Or, you may not _even_ parse your `"1/6/2016 12:00:00 AM"` string at first place if it is not a standard date and time format on `CurrentCulture` setting.

Comment: That's why using sortable `"s"` standard pattern is better because it is culture _independent_.

Comment: Ahh true, forgot about that part. Thank you @soner